# jax ws double tostring change format

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, number-formatting

We get the WSDLs from our customer. (I.e., we can't change them.)

The definition of one of the types looks something like this:

```
<complexType name="Type1">
  <complexContent>
<restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
  <sequence>
    <element name="value" minOccurs="0">
      <complexType>
    <complexContent>
      <restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
        <choice>
          <element name="bigdecimal" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}double"/>
          <element name="date" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}date"/>
          <element name="string" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
        </choice>
      </restriction>
    </complexContent>
      </complexType>
    </element>
    <element name="element2" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}integer" minOccurs="0"/>
  </sequence>
</restriction>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

resulting in things like

```
public void setBigdecimal(Double value) {
this.bigdecimal = value;
}
```

Now when we send a request with this type in it, it will generate something like this:

```
<rpcOp:value>
  <rpcOp:bigdecimal>10.0</rpcOp:bigdecimal> <!-- IN SPITE OF THE NAME, THIS IS A DOUBLE VALUE! -->
  <rpcOp:string>N</rpcOp:string>
</rpcOp:value>
```

The customer wants the content of  to be shown without decimal digits, i.e., 10 etc.

I suspect that when generating the request xml from the Java objects, the JAX-WS framework simply calls Double.toString(), which will inevitably add a decimal point and a decimal digit.

Is there a way to change this without being able to modify the WSDL? Register some custom number formatter for this type or something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found a solution. It looks something like this: (using JAXB)

xjc-serializable.xml :

```
...
<jaxb:globalBindings>
<xjc:serializable />
<!-- ADDED THIS: -->
<xjc:javaType name="java.lang.Double" xmlType="xs:double"
adapter="util.MyDoubleAdapter" />
</jaxb:globalBindings>
...
```

Then the java class:

```
public class MyDoubleAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Double> {

@Override
public String marshal(Double doubleValue) throws Exception {
    if (doubleValue == null) {
    return null;
    }
    String string = doubleValue.toString();
    if (string.endsWith(".0")) {
    string = string.replaceAll("\\.0", "");
    }
    return string;
}

public Double unmarshal(String stringValue) throws Exception {
    if (stringValue == null) {
    return null;
    }
    return Double.valueOf(stringValue);
}

}
```

And there you go.